# Why does my Site render so slowly on Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I am working on the following Site: https://fsa.thewire.ch
It's been working smoothly on Chrome. Now I have tested it on Safari and 1. the site loads more slowly and 2. and more importantly, the site only renders a little bit more than what is in the viewport. When I scroll through the page "quickly" it takes a while to load the content.
I'm using a landing image with a `$(window).load` function but safari doesn't seem to care about that. 
I don't experience the issue on other pages and my page is not extremely heavy. Also, the network tab doesn't show any issues.
What do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

Some jpg files, a svg file and this js: https://fsa.thewire.ch/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.4 spend a lot to be downloaded.
In some Safari configurations this can be a problem.
Try to resize the jpg files and check why this js file spend a lot of time to load

are you using wordpress?

good luck
Matias Creimerman

Comment: Maybe I can optimize the site further (although my client wants those high res images) but the problem is not with the site speed necessarily, if it just took a little longer to load everything it would be fine. The big problem is the only partial rendering of the page.
What can I do against it?